# Error while copying maven generated jar file in Docker file build stage

Tags: java, docker, maven, circleci, docker-build

I have a docker file having 2 stages. The first stage builds the application using maven and the  second one start the application. The file contents are as follows:-

```
FROM maven:3.8.3-openjdk-17 as maven_builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY up-user-service/pom.xml .
COPY up-user-service/src ./src
RUN mvn clean install
RUN ls -l /app/target


FROM openjdk:17-jdk-alpine as builder
COPY --from=maven_builder /app/target/*.jar up-user-service/target
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} application.jar
RUN java -Djarmode=layertools -jar application.jar extract
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-alpine
COPY --from=builder dependencies/ ./
RUN true
COPY --from=builder snapshot-dependencies/ ./
RUN true
COPY --from=builder spring-boot-loader/ ./
RUN true
COPY --from=builder application/ ./
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher"]
```

However, when I build this using docker file, I am getting the error `ERROR: failed to solve: lstat /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount1400144723/target: no such file or directory`. I am also unable to see the output of ls stage also as it disappears very fast from screen.

Can someone please suggest what might be the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete these two lines

```bash
# delete me!
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} application.jar
```

Those copy a jar file from your host system, any single `*.jar` file from the `target` directory relative to the build context; if you haven't separately built the application on your host this will fail.

Immediately before this you have the correct line

```bash
# keep me!
COPY --from=maven_builder /app/target/*.jar up-user-service/target
```

which copies the jar file built by the `maven_builder` stage.  With that line the jar file is in fact in your image, the second set of lines is redundant.

The one other tricky thing here is that you require the jar file to be named `application.jar` when you run the Spring unpacker, but the build output will probably be named something like `myapp-0.0.1.jar`.  I might rename this in the build stage:

```bash
FROM maven:3.8.3-openjdk-17 as maven_builder
...
RUN mvn clean install
RUN mv target/*.jar target/application.jar  # <-- add

FROM openjdk:17-jdk-alpine as builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=maven_builder /app/target/application.jar ./
RUN java -Djarmode=layertools -jar application.jar extract

FROM openjdk:17-jdk-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /app/dependencies/ ./
...
```

Comment: The step 3 succeeded after following your suggestion but getting an error step 4 'Error: Unable to access jarfile application.jar'. I also don't see the jar file copied from maven_builder to up-user-service/target which should have happened . What I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: That seems to match the suggestion in the last half of my answer: as you've written it you copy a jar file into `/up-user-service/target/myapp-0.0.1.jar`, but then you `RUN java -jar application.jar`.  So the last half of the answer suggests renaming the file to `application.jar` in the build stage, and consistently using a `/app` directory (not the container filesystem root directory) in all of the later stages.

Comment: I have already renamed the jar to application.jar as you suggested,but still getting the same error. I tried accessing the file as 'RUN java -Djarmode=layertools -jar up-user-service/target/application.jar extract' and 'RUN java -Djarmode=layertools -jar app/target/application.jar extract', but getting the same error.

Comment: Am I still missing anything?

Comment: Immediately before that `RUN` line you `COPY` the jar file into the intermediate stage.  The destination path of that `COPY` needs to match the jar file argument to `java -jar`.